# Evenly space hyperlink tags across a column in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to evenly space out 5 links for the top part of a footer on a webpage. I'm not sure how to go about doing this so that it remains evenly spaced and centered regardless of screen-size and window minimizing. the HTML I have for it so far is:

```
 <div id="topfooter">
    <div class="containter">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!--row-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--topfooter-->
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain more clear what you want?

Comment: Which bootstrap version do you use?

Comment: Version 3, I am just trying to have a list of hyperlinks displayed evenly horizontally across the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use more bootstrap!

```
<div id="topfooter">
    <div class="containter">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div> <!--row-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--topfooter-->
```

Comment: I had originally put each hyperlink in its own column but wasn't sure if this was the best way. I'll try this asap and update the question as answered depending on the results. Thank you!